# What does 1.e0 mean in the following code

Tags: c#, c++, c

What does 1.e0 mean in the following code

```
product *=
 ((1.e0-pow((double)2,i-32))*(1.e0-pow((double)2,i-32)))/(1.e0-pow((double)2,i-r));
```

It is c++ code, and how i can write 1.e0 in c#

Comment: try `1.0` since 1*(10 to the power of 0) is 1

Comment: You may want to google for c# number types, constants, formats etc.. until you come up with 1e0 ;-)

Comment: [Floating point literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal).

Comment: `1. == 1.0 == 1.00 = ... = 1e0 == 1.e0 == 1.0e0 == 1.00e0...`; all these numbers are `double` representation of `1`

Comment: I think that 1e0d may be more correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<number>e<power> = <number> * 10^<power>
```

Where the power is a power of ten. Basically the number after `e` tells you how many zeroes you have to append if it is positive. Negative powers make the number move by one digit to the right.

Examples

```
1.2e-3 = 1.2 * 10^-3 = 1.2 *    0.001 =    0.0012
1.2e-2 = 1.2 * 10^-2 = 1.2 *    0.01  =    0.012
1.2e-1 = 1.2 * 10^-1 = 1.2 *    0.1   =    0.12
1.2e0  = 1.2 * 10^0  = 1.2 *    1     =    1.2
1.2e1  = 1.2 * 10^1  = 1.2 *   10     =   12
1.2e2  = 1.2 * 10^2  = 1.2 *  100     =  120
1.2e3  = 1.2 * 10^3  = 1.2 * 1000     = 1200
```

You can see this notation on calculators. When the result is too large and would not fit into the display otherwise, the calculator automatically switches to the exponential notation.

[image]

In C# you would write the formula like this:

```
product *= (1 - Math.Pow(2, i - 32)) * (1 - Math.Pow(2, i - 32)) /
           (1 - Math.Pow(2, i - r));
```

The conversions to `double` happen automatically. One pair of parentheses is superfluous. One sub-expression occurs twice, you could write:

```
double temp = 1 - Math.Pow(2, i - 32);
product *= temp * temp / (1 - Math.Pow(2, i - r));
```

See:
- [Math.Pow Method (Double, Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx)  (msdn)

Answer (score 1):

Providing that `pow` is raising into power, C# code will be

```
product *= (1.0 - Math.Pow(2, i - 32)) *
           (1.0 - Math.Pow(2, i - 32)) /
           (1.0 - Math.Pow(2, i - r));
```

As you can see `1.e0` is just `1.0` - `double` representation of `1`